# How could I remove the "import error" I am receiving on Django

Tags: python, django

I am watching this video to learn more about Django https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7xjdXWZafY

### my code is exactly like his however I am getting an import error. It says "no modules named urls"

This is my code:

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('weather.urls')),
]
```

Comment: So as your above code snippet suggests, you should have `urls.py` file within your `weather` app directory. That's what the error is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to create a file called `urls.py` within your `weather` app. You can find further details on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs).